# Vue 3: access to data object inside component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

This code from Vue 3 documentation and it is working.

```
const data = { a: 1 }

// The object is added to a component instance
const vm = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return data
  }
}).mount('#app')

console.log(vm.a) // => 1
```

But, if I create the component using `render()` function, I cannot access the data object.

```
let options = window[this.data.get('index')];
options.baseUrl = window['baseUrl'];
const app2 = Vue.createApp({
     render() {
         const {h} = Vue;
             return h(app.component('ComponentA'), options)
         }
      })
     .mount("#app");

console.log(app2.baseUrl);  // undefined
console.log(app2.$data); // {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a normal data option and add that `options` to it :

```js
let options = {}
options.baseUrl = "someurl.com";
const app2 = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        options
      }
    },
    render() {

      const {
        h
      } = Vue;
      return h(Vue.createApp({}).component('ComponentA', {
        template: '<h1>hello</h1>'
      }))
    }
  })
  .mount("#app");

console.log(app2.options);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app" someVariable='some value'>
  Vue 3 app
</div>
```

Comment: well, I wanted to access the data object inside `ComponentA`. In your example, it seems I can only get options that I am passing to `app2`.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your `options` object has the wrong signature.
Try changing your options variable to:

```
let options = {
  data: {
    index: window[this.data.get('index')]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using render function *only* to pass the variables to it, you could also use `createApp`'s second parameter which will populate the props.

If you want to make changes to `options` reactive, you can use the `$props` as a reactive version of the `options` object. You can reassign `options` or use a new variable. This will make changes reactive in the application, so changing a value outside of app will update the app. Changes to `app2.baseUrl` will not be reactive, but `reactiveOptions.baseUrl` will be.

### Example:

```js
let options = { baseUrl: "localhost:3k/" }

const app2 = Vue.createApp({
  props: ['baseUrl'],
  template:'<h1>APP2 @{{ baseUrl }}</h1>'
}, options).mount("#app");

let reactiveOptions = app2.$props;

console.log(app2.baseUrl);
console.log(reactiveOptions);

function onClick(){
  reactiveOptions.baseUrl += "&key="
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.13/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>

<Button onclick="onClick()">change</Button>
```

Comment: well, my main purpose is to change the value of a variable in a data object which is being `watched` that triggers a specific action.

Comment: In that case it shouldn't matter whether you're using props or data. You could, however, use `options` as a starting point, and then have a reactive options object (like in the updated example). When the object is passed as props, the `$props` object will be reactive, so you could make changes directly to it.